# typecast bytes to array of uint64 in Python+numpy

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

If I have a 16-byte string, how can I cast it to an array of 2 uint64 in numpy? (specifying either little-endian or big-endian)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `np.fromstring`:

```
>>> n = range(16)
>>> s = ''.join(map(chr, n))
>>> np.fromstring(s, dtype=np.uint64)
array([506097522914230528, 1084818905618843912], dtype=uint64)
>>> sum((256**i)*x for i,x in enumerate(n[:8]))
506097522914230528L
>>> sum((256**i)*x for i,x in enumerate(n[8:]))
1084818905618843912L
```

although you'll have to flip endianness yourself.  And it's more of a conversion than a cast, although people often use cast pretty loosely.

Comment: At time of writing this, `np.fromstring()` is deprecated in favor of `np.frombuffer()` but otherwise the usage is exactly the same as DSM's answer above